# On the spectrum of the closure of a closable operator in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, spectral-theory

Let $A$ be a closable operator in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Do we have the following ?
$$\sigma (\bar{A})=\bar{\sigma}(A)$$
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that operators have a bounded inverse if and only if they are closed and bijective. This is a consequence of the open mapping theorem. Hence, if $A$ is closable but not closed, then its spectrum is all of $\mathbb{C}$. It follows that the relationship you above have is not true, as $\overline{\sigma(A)}$ would always be $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Very clear. Thank you.

Comment: @user536450 If you accept this as an answer--and you should--then press the checkmark to the left of the answer, and you can optionally +1 the answer as well.